# Factorise matrix determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I reduce this matrix to row echelon form and hence factorise the determinant, or is there a way that I am unaware of that factorise the determinant of this matrix without having to reduce it row echelon form given this is all I know and there exists no additional information.

$\left[
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    y+z+2x & y & z \\
    x & z+x+2y & z \\
    x & y & x+y+2z \\
  \end{array}
\right]$

Comment: Subtract from the third row the second one. Then in the result add to the second column the third one. In the second result add the second column to the first and subtract the first row from the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C_1\to C_1+C_2+C_3$. Take common from $C_1$. Then $R_2\to R_2-R_1$ and $R_3\to R_3-R_1$. Then   open along $R_1$. You will just have to multiply $2$ equal terms whn expanding.